# xelatex mathspec with polyglossia

Tags: math-mode, xetex, polyglossia, mathspec

How to use `mathspec` package and `polyglossia` for the russian language?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}    % \dif sign
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{microtype} % better management of overfulls


\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\begingroup\hyphenrules{english}}{\endgroup}
%\setallmainfonts[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Times New Roman}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{14}{14}{9}{7}


\begin{document}
  \(\lambda_{сист}\) --- интенсивность системы.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\(\lambda_{\text{сист}}\)`

Answer (score 3):

You have to tell XeLaTeX that the subscript is textual:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{microtype} % better management of overfulls


\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setTransitionsForLatin{\begingroup\hyphenrules{english}}{\endgroup}
\setallmainfonts[Mapping=tex-text, Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{14}{14}{9}{7}

\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\(\lambda_{\text{сист}}\) --- интенсивность системы.

\("f(x,y)\dif x+g(x,y)\dif y\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have removed the call to `commath` that I can't recommend. I added instead a good definition for `\dif`, certainly better than the wrong one given by `commath`.

However, I'd advise you to use a specialized math font instead of the clumsy `mathspec`.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\usepackage{microtype} % better management of overfulls


\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setTransitionsForLatin{\begingroup\hyphenrules{english}}{\endgroup}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{8}{6}
\DeclareMathSizes{14}{14}{9}{7}

\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\(\lambda_{\text{сист}}\) --- интенсивность системы.

\(f(x,y)\dif x+g(x,y)\dif y\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what I get if TeX Gyre Termes Math is used instead of XITS Math:

[image]